# Is it legal for one email service provider to send emails using the exact identical email address of another email service provider?

Tags: internet, email, internet-scam

Question -
Is it legal for one email service provider to send emails using the exact identical email address of another email service provider?

- This happened to me in the last 3 days. **The two companies are not connected**.
- I have an email account with company A, and used it to make an account with company B, and when I tried the email service of company B it uses the completely identical email address as my account with company A.
- I have replicated the problem (with company B) by using a 2nd account from company A.

**More Detail** -
Outlook.com apparently can send emails using gmail addresses, if you go through the steps. However, what about if you have no Microsoft accounts at all, then, you use your gmail address to make a Skype account, it may involve a verification code being sent to your gmail address. Then you decide to use your open Skype account to sign in to Outlook.com for the first time ever, and suddenly you notice that Outlook.com uses your gmail address to send emails, without you having in any way given any types of permissions to do anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

As people realize time and again in the fight against spam and scam, **the email protocol is not secure**. One can write anything into the "From" or "Reply-To" field. But that's for sending. To receive mail, the technical address has to be resolved.

An email address can consist of [two parts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), the *optional* display name and the *actual* address. Say Alice registers *"Alice and Bob" <alice@example.test>* and Bob registers *"Alice and Bob" <bob@other.sample>*. Those are different emails. One gets resolved at *example* in the *test* top level domain, the other gets resolved at *other* in the *sample* top level domain.

If two different companies can operate mailboxes with the same actual address, someone has "broken the internet" in a rather serious way, either locally on your network or globally. I do not think the internet is broken that way.

---

Which leaves the problem of identical display names. If the display name is trademarked or copyrighted, there could be problems, depending on details of the jurisdiction. It is usually not possible to copyright a personal name. There could also be questions of fraud. But those do not apply if the same person uses identical display names on different systems.

Comment: in other words: the network protocol does simply **not allow** two servers to have the exact same domain names.

Comment: It is also possible that two separately branded email service providers are actually the same company and that this fact has simply not been publicly disclosed.

Comment: @Trish, with admin access to the local machine and/or the DNS server, a name could be resolved differently for different calls. But that either advanced server administration or evil hacking.

Comment: Outlook.com apparently can send emails using gmail addresses, if you go through the steps. However, what about if you have no MS-accounts at all, then, you use your gmail address to make a Skype account, it may involve a verification-code being sent to your gmail address.  Then you decide to use your open Skype account to sign-in to Outlook.com for the first time ever, and suddenly you notice that Outlook.com uses your gmail address to send emails, without you having in any way given any types of permissions to do anything like that.

Comment: @number8989898989, analogies are not always helpful, but think of the *from:* header of a mail as the sender written on a physical letter, and the *to:* header as the recipient. Anybody can write any name and city of origin into on the envelope and throw the letter into a mailbox. But once the postal service has it, it gets stamped during processing and delivered to the recipient. Same with email. As to the legality of a piece of software using some known address belonging to the user for outgoing mails, that might be hidden in the fine print users click ...

Comment: Anything addressed to whatever@example.test should be sent automatically to the email server at example.test. If two companies tried to set up email servers for example.test, one of them should fail.

Comment: @gnasher729, different DNS servers could resolve the same name to different IPs. There can be legitimate reasons to do that within an intranet, or stressful (and hopefully short) moments as admins try to migrate servers without affecting the users.